# How to sort an NSArray with nested NSArray

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an instance of `NSArray` with instances of `NSArray` inside. The inner arrays contain only instances of `NSString`. I need to sort the nested arrays alphabetically by a selected index.

E.g.

```
@[
  @[@"test",@"B",@"test2"],
  @[@"bla",@"A",@"bla"],
  @[@"xyz",@"C",@"123"]
]
```

User selects index 1, Ascending sort. Result should be:

```
@[
  @[@"bla",@"A",@"bla"],
  @[@"test",@"B",@"test2"],
  @[@"xyz",@"C",@"123"]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"test",@"B",@"test2"],
                   @[@"bla",@"A",@"bla"],
                   @[@"xyz",@"C",@"123"]];

NSInteger index = 1;

NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    return [obj1[index] compare:obj2[index] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
}];
```

Clearly, if the subarrays have different number of items or if they're not all strings, you might include some additional logic to handle that, but it illustrates the basic idea.